# jQuery off canvas not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an off canvas feature set up and I can't get it to work properly.

It doesn't slide back to the left side when trying to close it. It works fine when I use 250px instead of 90% but I need percentage!

http://jsfiddle.net/3Wdby/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#push, #close').click(function () {
        var $navigacia = $('body, #slide-menu'),
            val = $navigacia.css('left') === '90%' ? '0px' : '90%';
        $navigacia.animate({
            left: val
        }, 300)    
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch the if statement to check if it's 0px instead of 90% because when you look if it's 90% it will return in pixels

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#push, #close').click(function () {
        console.log($('body, #slide-menu').css('left'));
        var $navigacia = $('body, #slide-menu'),
            val = $navigacia.css('left') === '0px' ? '90%' : '0px';
        $navigacia.animate({
            left: val
        }, 300)
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Wdby/2/)

Comment: thanks a lot, I knew there must be a simple solution to this. Couldn't figure out which way to go...

Comment: I have one more question though. I implemented this and in Chrome, the first click doesn't work. It toggles on the second click after the page loads

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test for percentages, instead you should invert your if statement:

```
val = $navigacia.css('left') === '0px' ? '90%' : '0';
```

It tests if the width is 0, if it is 0 it sets it to 90%. When you next click, because the width is not 0, it sets it back to 0.